# how to remove left side drop down Menu on jinternal frame title Bar java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jinternalframe

1. How to remove or hide the left side Drop Down Menu only on jinternal frame Title Bar and not to remove or hide whole Title Bar.
2. How to set not Move jinternal frame by mouse holding in jdesktop pane.

Check below snapshot for better understand my question what I want:

http://i49.tinypic.com/1zfned2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way is to use your own UI delegate for the internal frame. See http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html for an article explaining how UI delegates work.

Since you seem to use the Synth look n' feel, you should be able to easily create your own subclass of `SynthInternalFrameUI`, that would override the `createNorthPane()` method in order to create and return an instance of a custom subclass of `SynthInternalFrameTitlePane`.

This custom title pane would in turn override the `addSubComponents()` method in order to not add the `menuButton`. I've not tested all that, so maybe you'll need to override additional methods.

Comment: thanks for help.....drop down menu removed but now how i can set un-movalbe the jinternal frame in desktop pane by holding mouse click ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. You want the internal frame to be impossible to move? If so, you'll probably need to customize the UI delegate further. Look at the source code where the listeners are added.

Comment: sorry for my weak English....i want How to set unmovable to JInternalFrame in desktop pane ? means to stop the moving of jinternal frame in desktop pane...

Comment: If the JInternalFrame is in a JDesktopPane, you can try setting that JDesktopPane to use your own DesktopManager which delegates all methods except `beginDraggingFrame`, `dragFrame` and `endDraggingFrame` to the JDesktopPane's default DesktopManager.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** how to remove or hide the left side Drop Down Menu only on jinternal frame Title Bar and not to remove or hide whole Title Bar. **source code:**

```
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame.getUI();
Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
north.remove(0);
north.validate();
north.repaint();
```

**2.** how to set not Move jinternal frame by mouse holding in jdesktop pane. **source code:**

```
 for(MouseListener listener : ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane().getMouseListeners()){
        ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) internalFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane().removeMouseListener(listener);
        }
```

Thanks